# How can I skip groups while subsetting with key by in data.table?

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, aggregate, subset

I have this DT:

```
dt=data.table(ID=c(rep(letters[1:2],each=4),'b'),value=seq(1,9))
   ID value
1:  a     1
2:  a     2
3:  a     3
4:  a     4
5:  b     5
6:  b     6
7:  b     7
8:  b     8
9:  b     9
```

I need to eliminate groups while subsetting but only when the data fulfils some condition. Something like this does not work:

```
dt[,{if (.N==4) .SD else NULL
     v1},by="ID"]
```

So that I need to remove the groups that do not meet the condition. In this example I would like to skip the groups which length is different than 4. So that I get:

```
   ID value
1:  a     1
2:  a     2
3:  a     3
4:  a     4
```

But I haven't been able to work this around, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: does `dt[, if (.N==4) .SD, by="ID"]` answer your question?

Comment: Actually yes!... I feel so dumb hahahaha

Comment: @ jangorecki: why not posting?

Comment: @jangorecki, how did you manage to know this notation?, why adding the null won't work?... sometimes I feel like the notation is a matter of memory but I'm sure there is a logical way behind it that I just haven't studied yet

Comment: There's a FR for syntax like `DT[,.SD, by=ID, having={.N == 4L}]` https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788 fyi

Comment: could one of you add his answers?

Comment: @AldoPareja adding `NULL` works exactly the same (since that's what omitting the `else` does): `dt[,if (.N==4) .SD else NULL, by = ID]` - the only problem in that expression of yours is that out of nowhere `v1`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel was away, I don't mind Raphael post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jangorecki came up with the answer:

does `dt[, if (.N==4) .SD, by="ID"]` answer your question?